# Como manter a marcação de um radioButton ao rolar uma listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Boa tarde, possuo uma listView editada e dentro dela eu possuo um radioGroup. Preciso que ao rolar a listView, a marcação no radioGroup  não perca sua marcação.

Segue o xml.

```
 <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sim"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/nao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Não"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sim"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/na"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NA"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questao"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nao"
            />
            </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: A sua ListView usa um adapter que, por sua vez, acessa um Array (provavelmente de objetos) onde cada item da ListView deve estar associado a uma instância desse objeto numa determinada posição do array. O que você tem que fazer é guardar no objeto o status de cada radio como uma váriável no objeto e, sempre que alterar o status, você tem que atualizar o objeto correspondente e depois notificar o Adapter que houveram alterações no mesmo.

Comment: Poste seu código, pois eu nunca vi esse comportamento em uma listviewm pode ser alguma coisa na sua implementação que não esta mantendo o radiobutton em seu estado